# Stop read(2) once there is nothing else to read in a file descriptor

Tags: c, fork, pipe, file-descriptor

I would like to read in a file descriptor line by line until there is nothing else to read. I expected read(2) to return zero when the end of the file descriptor is reach, but on the contrary, it seems to wait for the file descriptor to be closed. I would like to avoid closing my file descriptor as I have more to write in it.

Here is a comprehensive example I have done :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

size_t read_line(int fd, char* buffer);

int main()
{
    int fd[2];

    if (pipe(fd) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Pipe error.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (fork() == 0) {
        close(fd[0]);
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
            dprintf(fd[1], "FOO\n");
        pause();
        exit(0);
    }

    close(fd[1]);

    char buffer[20];
    while (read_line(fd[0], buffer) > 0)
        printf("%s\n", buffer);

    printf("BAR !!\n");

    exit(0);
}

size_t read_line(int fd, char* buffer)
{
    char char_buf;
    size_t buffer_size = 0;
    while (read(fd, &char_buf, 1) > 0 && char_buf != '\n')
        buffer[buffer_size++] = char_buf;
    buffer[buffer_size] = '\0';

    return buffer_size;
}
```

My read_line function should be returning zero at the end. It works properly if I replace "pause();" with "close(fd[1]);", but obviously, it is not my goal as I would avoid to loose the pipe.

Thanks !

Comment: You mean [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) in your title, and you want [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html). Consider also [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html).

Comment: What exactly you are trying to do? Check whether more data is coming from pipe or not before the other side decides to close it?

Comment: how would you know there won't be any data coming while keeping the pipe open? try to use epoll or select to set a timeout. or use specific encoding to pass information you want.

Comment: End of a pipe occurs when the peer closes his end, not just when there is no data currently available to be read.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this by checking the return value of read. The reason being that while the file descriptor is empty, read will just wait. Your problem is similar to that of waiting until you have no input from a scanf, if that makes it easier for you to understand.

A solution is to have a specific value which will stop the loop. For example if you were reading non-negative integers, this value could be -1.

Another solution comes from the fact that if a pipe is empty and no process has the pipe open for write, a read returns 0. So when you are done writing, close the file destriptor p[1].(p[1] must also be closed from the sender process).